# Making a div having no contents scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

```
<div id="dummyHorizontalDiv" style="height:16px !important;width: 550px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
      <div id="dummyScrollArea" style="width: 750px;">
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a horizontal scroll bar on `div` with `id=dummyHorizontalDiv` but since there is no content in the inner div(though its width is more than that of the outer div), I am not getting the horizontal scroll bar.

Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Your code works for me and I see the horizontal scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ4Yw/1/

Comment: it works for me... can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? also, add "overflow-x: scroll;" for dummyHorizontalDiv, it will force the scroll bar to show no matter what

Comment: @xbonez LOL, both in almost the same time, 10 sec difference (:

Comment: Because you gave the inner div a height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have scrollbars, but your dummyHorizontalDiv is actually too short to display them - browsers will not draw in scrollbars if they would be bigger than the element they're scrolling. Change your 16px height to something like 30px and you'll see the scroll bar appear.

Answer (score 1):

Give `div#dummyScrollArea` some height.

Answer (score 0):

try display:block - if you don't specify that, the width and height are sort of "suggestions" in the world of CSS

see here: http://laughingsquid.com/wp-content/uploads/css-is-awesome-20090407-142244.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you've to make 2 changes in your code to make that working, those are:

1. Increase the outer DIV(#dummyHorizontalDiv) height, because the current height(16px) is not enough to show scroll bars.
2. Set some height to the inner DIV(#dummyScrollArea).

Adjusted code block is specified below, check it once and then let me know if still that's not working for you.

```
<div id="dummyHorizontalDiv" style="height:30px !important;width: 550px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="dummyScrollArea" style="width: 750px; height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```